# Can "小畑" be read as "Emiriya", and how?

Tags: kanji, readings, names

According to [this entry on Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/Emiriya%20%23names), the Kanji "小畑" could be read as "Emiriya" (えみりや).

However - no On'yomi, Kun'yomi, or any combination of [小](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F#Readings) and [畑](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%95%91#Readings) readings I could find seem to indicate if / how that is possible.

Is there a "formal" way to explain this? Are there other Kanji options?

I've no formal knowledge of how Japanese names are constructed (other than something about a government regulation that only jinmeiyō / jōyō kanji can be used?) so honestly I'll take what I can get ^^;

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

That `#names` function of jisho.org has been severely broken (or tainted) for a long time, and you should not believe anything from it. See [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68019/5010). I am surprised that jisho.org still hasn't fixed this obvious problem—it still says [いしだ is a valid reading of 佐々木](https://jisho.org/search/%23names%20%E4%BD%90%E3%80%85%E6%9C%A8) and [えりりん is a valid reading of 田村](https://jisho.org/search/%23names%20%E7%94%B0%E6%9D%91)!

In Japan, the spelling (kanji) and the pronunciation of a person name can be registered separetely, so it is at least "legal" to have a baby whose spelling is 小畑 and whose reading is えみりや (see [this discussion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18332/5010)). Nevertheless, 小畑 is a **surname** to begin with, and it's almost never given as a first name with an arbitrary reading. Also, if the spelling and the pronunciation are irrelevant to this extent, the government usually will not accept such a registration. Since the database contains many other clearly wrong names, I can assure you that this えみりや is 99.99% a hoax, too.

The correct reading of 小畑 is おばた (or sometimes おばたけ, こばたけ, こはた).

Comment: Ah, I figured it might've been wires crossing on Jisho's side 

That said, I know おばた is a surname, but is there something that clearly defines "小畑" as one? (As in, using surname-specific Kanji or being on a pre-made list of surnames or something?)

Comment: @djohoe28 There is no such thing as a full list of surnames (there isn't one in English, either), but a native speaker knows what can be a surname and what can be a given name.

Comment: Hm, apparently there *is* such an entry in [the source dictionary](https://www.edrdg.org/jmdictdb/cgi-bin/entr.py?svc=jmdict&sid=&e=1541723). Possibly it should be removed there…

Answer (score 1):

小畑 is not normally read as Emiriya. I'm pretty sure it's just a mistake - an artifact made during format conversion or something.

That said, I believe there is no statutory regulation on readings of kanji used in names in Japan. That is the reason why [kira kira names](https://japantoday.com/category/features/lifestyle/what-are-%27kira-kira%27-names-and-why-japanese-parents-choose-them-for-their-kids) exist.

Comment: Woah, I'd never heard of this trend!
Admittedly, I'd probably be guilty of it too 
Are names like "光 as ライト" (from the article) possible because Japanese name registration forms include a "Read as" section, or do they use Furigana or something?